# Make a box with images fit for all resolutions

Tags: html, css, resolution

I know this is a wide subject and many resolutions, but I thought that I had it solved by using width.
This is in 1920x1050: [image: view]
and this is with 1600x900: [image]

This is the code:

```
div.content {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 80px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 6px inset silver;
    clear: none;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 40px 40px;
}

div.content img.small {
    width: 15.5%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

What do I need to do to make it always look like image 1, but if the screen is less wide then it should just be less images, but it should always fit?

Comment: Give the images a pixel width, don't let them wrap lines and don't show the overflow on their parent element. `white-space:nowrap` takes care of the not wrapping to the next line.

Comment: This is what I have now: http://i.imgur.com/djVDBSW.png with 250 width, and in the content I put the white-space: nowrap;

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle so we can test out your code with the images and html included.

Comment: @user3068228 Now you've got to set the `overflow` on the element that makes the box around the images. Right now the default `overflow` value is being used, `auto`. Also, JSFiddle is your friend, setup your CSS and HTML in JSFiddle and let us play with it instead of posting screenshots (which are still helpful, just not as helpful).

Answer (score 0):

The key to making modern responsive layouts is using media queries. Set breakpoints (using screen width in pixels is common) that makes sense for your layout. For example, if you want to show fewer images on a line at 600px viewport width something like this would do the trick;

```
.content img {
    width: 20%; /* 5 images default */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .content img {
        width: 25%; /* 4 images when window is less than 500px */
    }
}
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/6p2yM/ (resize the window width to see that the number of images changes with window size)